# react merging two components and sorting data by date and time (newest at top oldest and bottom)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have codes below

```
code removed
```

The problem is it prints rows of expenses and then rows of incomes (i.e posts from expenses are printed first then after them incomes are printed).
I need them to be mixed in and printed accordingly by date and time (newest post goes to top and oldest at bottom)

Comment: You want to merge `ExpenseRow` and `IncomeRow` too or keep them separate? Seemingly, there are mergable.

Comment: Wait, so is there duplicate data between ````ExpenseRow```` and ````IncomeRow```` or does all the data need to be displayed?  Is there some commonality between them like ````title````?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To minimize your code change, I'd propose to add another state called `row` and use `componentDidUpdate` to listen to `expenses` and `incomes` states change for `row` state update.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ExpenseRow from './ExpenseRow';
import IncomeRow from './IncomeRow';

class IncomeExpenseSummary extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            expenses:[],
            incomes:[],
            rows: []
        }
    }
   
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
       //trigger when incomes or expenses change
       if(prevState.incomes !== this.state.incomes || prevState.expenses !== this.state.expenses) {
          //add type to recognize `income` in mixed list
          const updatedIncomes = [...this.state.incomes].map(income => ({...income, type: 'income'})) 
          //add type to recognize `expense` in mixed list
          const updatedExpenses = [...this.state.expenses].map(expense => ({...expense, type: 'expense'})) 
          //sort all rows with the mixed list
          const sortedRows = [...updatedExpenses, ...updatedIncomes].sort((a,b) => new Date(b.created_at) - new Date(a.created_at)) 
          this.setState({ rows: sortedRows })
       }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getExpenseList();
        this.getIncomeList();
    }

    getExpenseList = () =>{
        //if you use an arrow function, you don't need to pass variable for `this`
        axios.get('/get/expenses',{
            params:{_limit: 3}
        }).then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                expenses: response.data
            });
        });
    }

    getIncomeList =() =>{
        //if you use an arrow function, you don't need to pass variable for `this`
        axios.get('/get/incomes',{
            params:{_limit: 3}
        }).then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                incomes: response.data
            });
        });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <table className="table"> 
                {/* <toast/> */}
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Date</th>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Price</th>
                        <th scope="col">Category</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
      <tbody>
            {this.state.rows.map((row) => row.type === 'expense' ? <ExpenseRow data={row} key={row.title}/> : <IncomeRow data={row} key={row.title}/>)}
      </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
    );
    }
  }


export default IncomeExpenseSummary;
```

Comment: I think I lacked one bracket in `map`. Could you try it again with the updated code? @Bekr

Comment: okay, just a second

Comment: I got no errors this time, but It doesn't print anything, I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Could you add `console.log({ sortedRow })` before this line `this.setState({ rows: sortedRows })` and check what you get? @Bekr

Comment: and check what you have in `this.state.expenses` and `this.state.incomes` too. They're potentially empty @Bekr

Comment: That's weird, because I defined it here though `const sortedRows = [...updatedExpenses, ...updatedIncomes].sort((a,b) => b.created_at - a.created_at)`. Where did you add that `console.log`?

Comment: Right before this line - this.setState({ rows: sortedRows })

Comment: How about values for `updatedExpenses` and `updatedIncomes`? They're also empty? @Bekr

Comment: I also get this error "Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops."

Comment: I just updated this condition, `prevState.incomes !== this.state.incomes`. Could you update yours too? @Bekr

Comment: Luckily, we come this far, I think the last problem is `sort`. You can modify the sort to something like this `sort((a,b) => new Date(b.created_at) - new Date(a.created_at))` @Bekr

Comment: Thank you Nick, could you guide me how I could add filter function, for example adding date field and selecting month, then it prints the result :D ?

Comment: Hmm that will be another huge implementation... But I can give you a brief idea. You can add this logic to your filter function `[...rows].filter(row => new Date (row.created_at) + 1 === monthValue)` and update it back to `rows` state. `monthValue` will be from your drop-down list event `onChange`, and values for that drop-down list is 1 to 12. @Bekr

Answer (score 1):

If you are aren't worried about rendering duplicate data, this should work for you.  I simply merged the two states, sorted them by date, and passed that to your new combined component `ExpenseIncomeRow`. If you are actually trying to merge the data based on `key/value` properties, then this solution may not be ideal for you.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ExpenseIncomeRow from './ExpenseIncomeRow';

class IncomeExpenseSummary extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            expenses:[],
            incomes:[],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getExpenseList();
        this.getIncomeList();
    }

    sortByDate = (data) => {
        data.sort((a, b) => new Date(b['created_at']) - new Date(a['created_at']))
    }

    getExpenseList =() =>{
        let self=this;
        axios.get('/get/expenses',{
            params:{_limit: 3}
        }).then(function(response)
            {self.setState({
                expenses: response.data
            });
        });
    }

    getIncomeList =() =>{
        let self=this;
        axios.get('/get/incomes',{
            params:{_limit: 3}
        }).then(function(response)
            {self.setState({
                incomes: response.data
            });
        });
    }


    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <table className="table"> 
                {/* <toast/> */}
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Date</th>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Price</th>
                        <th scope="col">Category</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.sortByDate(this.state.expenses.slice(0, 4).concat(this.state.incomes.slice(0, 4)).map(function(x, i){
                    return <ExpenseIncomeRow key={i} data={x} />
                }))}
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default IncomeExpenseSummary;
```

Here is the new component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'


class ExpenseIncomeRow extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <tr className='alert alert-success'>
                <th>{this.props.data.created_at}</th>
                <td>{this.props.data.title}</td>
                <td>{this.props.data.amount}</td>
                <td>{this.props.data.category}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
}
export default ExpenseIncomeRow;
```

I have changed your `imports` but you will actually have to set up a new component on your end for it to work properly.

Comment: Hmm, I tried running this code, It doesn't print anything, I checked the console and it says Uncaught ReferenceError: sortByDate is not defined

Comment: @Bekr oops!  I forgot to put ````this.```` next to ````sortByDate````.  Add that and see how it works.

Comment: How is it running now?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding a `zip()` helper:

```js
// Zip array arguments together.
//
//     zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
//     //=> [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
//     zip([1], [2, 3], [])
//     //=> [[1, 2, undefined], [undefined, 3, undefined]]
//
function zip(...arrays) {
  if (!arrays.length) return [];
  const length = Math.max(...arrays.map(array => array.length));
  return Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => arrays.map(array => array[i]));
}
```

If you are already using a library with helper functions (Underscore.js, Lodash, Ramda, etc.), chances are that this function is available through it.

You can then use it within your JSX in the following manner:

```
// moved taking the first 3 elements up, to simplify the JSX
const take = (n, array) => array.slice(0, n + 1);
const expenses = take(3, this.state.expenses);
const incomes = take(3, this.state.incomes);

// ...

<tbody>
  {zip(expenses, incomes).map(([expense, income], i) => (
    <>
      <ExpenseRow key={i} data={expense} />
      <IncomeRow key={i} data={income} />
    </>
  ))}
</tbody>
```

This solution assumes the HTTP request returns the items in the correct order. If this isn't the case, you'll need to sort both the arrays first.

---

If the length of `expenses` and `incomes` can be different. Say `expenses` has length `1` and `incomes` has length `3`. Then you'll probably want to add an additional check for both `expenses` and `incomes` (example only shows `expenses`).

```
{expense && <ExpenseRow key={i} data={expense} />}
```

Or you could return `null` in `ExpenseRow` if no data is provided.

```
class ExpenseRow extends Component {
    render() {
        if (!this.props.data) return null;
        // ...
    }
}
```